# How to extract a list of selected cells into a CSV file

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, extract

I have a huge Excel sheet and I would like to get a small list of cell (around 200-300 cells from the same column, row) into a CSV string.

Is there an Excel command to do that?. Saving the file into a CSV is not much of a help as the file is quite huge.

Comment: Would it be an option to just copy the selected area and paste it into another worksheet? This would be quite simple with VBa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a VBA-macro. Change the range, to whatever you want. I choose A1:B3. Also you should change the filepath to a path, which you like.

```
Sub CopyToCSV()
Sheets(1).Range("A1:B3").Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Temp\yourCSV.csv" _
    , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

**How to add a button to the excel-sheet to execute the macro**

> 1. Add a button (Form control)
>
>    1. If the Developer tab is not available, display it.
>
>       1. Click the Microsoft Office Button Button image, and then click Excel Options.
>       2. In the Popular category, under Top options for working with Excel, select the Show Developer tab in the Ribbon check box, and then
>            click OK.
> 2. On the Developer tab, in the Controls group, click Insert, and then under ActiveX Controls, click Command Button Button image.
>
>    [image: Controls group]
> 3. Click the worksheet location where you want the upper-left corner of the command button to appear.
> 4. In the *Controls group*, click *View Code*.  
>    This starts the Visual Basic Editor. Make sure that Click is selected in the dropdown
>      list on the right. The sub procedure called `CommandButton1_Click`, as
>      shown in the following picture, runs two macros when the button is
>      clicked.

[*Source*](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-a-button-and-assign-a-macro-to-it-in-a-worksheet-HP010236676.aspx)

Now just repace the code of the `CommandButton1_Click`with the code inside the sub which I've posted on top of this.